# skip iteration in for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem with if statement in for loop.

I am getting list of files from directory `filesSAS` loop through them and each one converting from `csv` to `JSON`. after that i check if output has id in their object if yes copy file `(copyFile(dirSas, dirOut, filename)` if id is present add Date and save as CSV.

problem is that in frist iteration it copy the file but it is also executing `saveCSV` function which overrides my result. What i want to achive is to if id is not present copy file and that it for this iteration, go for another iteration. I was trying to put saveCSV inside for loop with no luck

EDIT: when my for loop hit object with no id i want to copy file. when id is present i want to add date to it and save as csv

```
let noId = [{
user:"Mark",
job:"Job"
}]

let withId = [{
id:1,
user:"Mark",
job:"Job"

}]

output
 let withId = [{
    id:1,
    user:"Mark",
    job:"Job"
    date: 12-09-2019
    }]


const saveNewFile = async (filesSAS, dirSas, dirOut, dirArchive) => {
  filesSAS.forEach(async filename => {
    const newData = await csv().fromFile(`${dirSas.path}/${filename}`);
    for await (const iterator of object) {
      if (iterator.Id === null || iterator.Id === undefined) {
        await copyFile(dirSas, dirOut, filename);
      }
      rec.Date = moment(Date.now()).format("DD-MMM-YYYY");
    }

    await saveCSV(newData, `${dirOut.path}/${filename}`, "output");
  });
};
```

regards

Comment: You could try to use a flag to decide if `saveCSV` should run or not

Comment: how to use flag? new concept for me

Comment: var flag = true; if (flag) saveCSV(); and if you don't want to run saveCSV change flag to false

Comment: Posting more complete code would probably help.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be achieved with a boolean that we update in case we don't find an id

```
const saveNewFile = async (filesSAS, dirSas, dirOut, dirArchive) => {
  filesSAS.forEach(async (filename, index) => {
    const newData = await csv().fromFile(`${dirSas.path}/${filename}`);
    for await (const iterator of object) {
      if (iterator.Id === null || iterator.Id === undefined) {
        await copyFile(dirSas, dirOut, filename);
      }
      else {
          rec.Date = moment(Date.now()).format("DD-MMM-YYYY");
          await saveCSV(newData, `${dirOut.path}/${filename}`, "output");
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: hey i tried that return before but it looks like not working. what i want to achive is if id  is not present just copy file so exectute function in if block. if not go to next line add Date and save as CSV, problem is that when i retunr in if even if id is presnt date is not added

Comment: Hey sorry I didn't understand before, so you always want the date to be updated, but saveCSV only if we have an Id and copyFile only if we don't?

Comment: @Exc what you didn't say is if you want to call saveCSV if absolutely no Id are defined in the whole array or if only in one case Id is not defined

Comment: i only want to call saceCSV what id is present so i can add date to object

Comment: @Exc but there could be many Id in your object, some of them might be defined and some of them not defined. What happens in that case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197827/discussion-between-alexandre-senges-and-exc).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does have the `continue` statement, which jumps over one iteration of a loop:
[JavaScript Break and Continue](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp)

However, I think the fact that your loop is asynchronous makes it hard to restart the loop in a sequential fashion.  You can always just use an `if` statement to not do the remainder of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I mange to do it with refactor

```
const saveNewFile = async (filesSAS, dirSas, dirOut, dirArchive) => {
  filesSAS.forEach(async filename => {
    const newData = await csv().fromFile(`${dirSas.path}/${filename}`);
    if (!newData[0].hasOwnProperty(pkCol)) {
      copyFile(dirSas, dirOut, filename);
    } else {
      for await (const rec of newData) {
        rec.DateCreated = moment(Date.now()).format("DD-MMM-YYYY");
      }
      await saveCSV(newData, `${dirOut.path}/${filename}`, "output");
    }
  });
};
```